# Angular $http: display upload progress (using NodesJS backend & formidable)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, upload, formidable

This app uses an Angular frontend to upload files from the local computer. I'm trying to display progress update (to show the user it's not crashed during long uploads).

Frontend code:

```
function uploadFile(file, uploadUrl){

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    var config = {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }

    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, config).then(onSuccess, onError, onUpdate);

        function onSuccess(event){
            console.log('upload complete');
        }

        function onError(event){
            console.log('upload failed');
        };

        function onUpdate(event){
            console.log(event.config.file.name);
        }
}
```

The NodeJS backend uses Formidable to handle file uploads:

```
var formidable = require('formidable');

function handle(req, res){

    var currentFile = null;    
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req);

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
        currentFile = file.name;
        file.path = config.folder_uploads + file.name;
    });

    form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        console.log('>' + currentFile + ' uploaded ' + (bytesReceived / 1000000).toFixed(2) + " / " + (bytesExpected / 1000000).toFixed(2) + " MB.");
    });

    form.on('file', function (name, file){
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });

    form.on('end', function(){
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
```

I haven't found a way to use the response or the form the notify the frontend of any progress made. What's to do, backend side, to send progress notifications?